# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\frac{1}{nx}$ on $(0,+\infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\frac{1}{nx}$$
converge uniformly on $(0,+\infty)$? First, I guessed that it does, but Abel's test is not applicable here because $\sin\frac{1}{nx}$ is not monotonic, other tools didn't seem to help either. Now I think that there's no uniform convergence, but I can't prove it as well. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean uniform convergence of the given expression to a function?

Comment: @Shakespeare, yes. In other words, do the partial sums of the series converge uniformly to its sum (which is, obviously, some function of $x$).

Comment: Contrarian comment.  Given $N$, can you find an $x$ (close to zero) so that $$(-1)^{n+1}\sin\frac{1}{nx} > \frac{1}{2}$$ for $1\le n \le N$ ??

Comment: @GEdgar, I doubt that, because $\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\frac{1}{nx}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n}$, and $f_n(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\frac{1}{nx}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: That's why I left out an $n$.

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed. Well, I'm not sure I can...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof that there is *no* uniform convergence.

For any integer $s$ divisible by $2^t$ but not by $2^{t+1}$, let me denote $\tau(s)=s/2^t$. Now consider a sufficiently large integer $m=4u$. I denote $g(m)=\tau(m+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot\tau(2m)$ and $\xi(m)=2g(m)+ \pi m/2$, and also $$\alpha_n(m)=(-1)^{n+1}\sin\frac{\xi(m)}{n}.$$ I claim that $\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}\alpha_n(m)/n>1/8$, which would imply the lack of uniform convergence.

Note that, for any odd $\mu\in\{m,\ldots,2m\}$, the number $2g(m)/\mu$ is an even integer, so that $\alpha_\mu(m)=\sin(\pi m/(2\mu))\geqslant\sin(\pi/4)>0.7$. Similarly, if $\mu$ divides two but not four, $2g(m)/\mu$ is an odd integer, and again $\alpha_\mu(m)>0.7$. Trivially, $\alpha_\mu(\mu)\geqslant-1$ in other cases.

Thus we have, for any $v\in\{m/4,\ldots,m/2\}$, that $$\sigma_v:=\sum_{n=4v-3}^{4v}\alpha_n(m)/n>\frac{0.7}{4v-3}+\frac{0.7}{4v-2}+\frac{0.7}{4v-1}-\frac{1}{4v}>\frac{2.1}{4v}-\frac{1}{4v}>\frac{1}{4v}.$$ Therefore, $$\sum_{n=m}^{2m}\alpha_n(m)/n=\sum_{v=u+1}^{2u}\sigma_v>\sum_{v=u+1}^{2u}\frac{1}{4v}>\frac{1}{8}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got your idea. But I have just one question: when you estimate $\sigma_v$ from below, shouldn't the fourth term be $-\frac{1}{4v-3}$?

Comment: I meant that $$\sum_{n=4v-3}^{4v}\alpha_n(m)/n=\frac{\alpha_{4v-3}}{4v-3}+\frac{\alpha_{4v-2}}{4v-2}+\frac{\alpha_{4v-1}}{4v-1}+\frac{\alpha_{4v}}{4v}>$$ $$\frac{0.7}{4v-3}+\frac{0.7}{4v-2}+\frac{0.7}{4v-1}-\frac{1}{4v}>2.1\cdot\frac{0.7}{4v}-\frac{1}{4v}>1/4v.$$ But, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: OK, thanks, I see now: the last term is the one corresponding to the number divisible by 4, so you don't use any estimate for the denominator and leave it as it is ($4v$). Let me look into it a little bit more before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

this is an alternate series, and for a fixed x, we can find an No such as $\frac{1}{n*x}$ is always smaller than pi/2 (I want the monotony of sin), if n>=No.

So if we write the general term $(-1)^\left(n+1\right)*Vn(x)$, we have:

(Vn(x)) decreases, Vn(x)-->0, when n--> ∞, so the theorem about the rest of alternate series can be used here:

The rest verify: |Rn(x)| ~ |Vn(x)|, with Rn(x) = $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty Vk(x)$

So |Rn(x)| ~ $\frac{1}{x*n^2}$ , with the inequality : |Rn(x)| =< $|V_n(x)|$ =< $\frac{1}{x*n^2}$

So you have the uniform convergence on every interval of the type [A;+∞[ using a "standard" theorem , but not on [0;+∞[. And the latter is wrong, as proven by the accepted answer.

Comment: You did not prove that the convergence is not uniform on $[0,+\infty).$

Comment: You are very right, I didn't not express myself correctly. This is a proof that a weaker result can be achieved using a "conventional" about alternate series, but not the one the OP was asking. A correct counter example was indeed given by User2097