# Confusion about uniform convergence of a functional alternating series!!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

This question has already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964194/uniform-convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n1n-sin-fr) that I unfortunately didn't understand....

First, I proved pointwise convergence easily after expanding $sin(\frac{1}{nx})$ ( taylor expansion near zero ).

When it came to uniform convergence, I did this:

$|R_n(x)| = |\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\sin\frac{1}{kx}| \leq |\frac{\sin\frac{1}{(n+1)x}}{n+1}| \leq \frac{1}{n+1} \longrightarrow 0$.

Please WHY doesn't it converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$??

I saw an answer that it DOES converge uniformly on $[A,\infty)$, but what is the problem in our domain?!!

When I saw this question, I felt disappointed as I have an exam tomorrow!

I think the main problem is that our doctor gave us only 2 ways ( normal convergence and remainder term ) to check the uniform convergence despite the fact they're many!! Please help me.

Comment: I think your formula is incorrect. It should be $$\left|\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} \sin \frac{1}{kx}\right| \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sin \frac{1}{kx}}{k}\right| \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$$ which diverges. So one cannot concludes the series is uniformly convergent using Weierstrass's M-test.

Comment: I used the fact that in an alternating series, the first term dominates. Why is this incorrect here?

Comment: I took it as a theorem, and my doctor insisted on using it whenever we have alternating series: If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^na_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=M}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges $\forall M$ and $|a_M| \geq |\sum_{k=M+1}^{\infty}(-1)^ka_k|$.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to use the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) on
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\,\sin\left(\frac1{kx}\right)\tag{1}
$$
to get that the absolute value of the sum is no greater than the absolute value of the first term, which is no greater than $\frac1{n+1}$.

Unfortunately, the Alternating Series Test requires the terms to be alternating in sign and decreasing in absolute value; that is not the case in $(1)$ when $x$ gets close to $0$.

Comment: Aha.. Is this because we will get $sin\infty$ which doesn't exist?

Comment: Is my work good for $x\in [A,+\infty)$ as the terms are then decreasing in absolute value?

Comment: Yes; past a certain $n$, the terms will be decreasing on $[A,+\infty)$.